# %by macro statement within %do loop not working as I would need

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro, do-loops

I have a problem with a %by statement within a %do-loop inside a SAS macro: when I run this piece of code

```
%let Today = 22;
%let last_day_prev = 31;

%MACRO Rename;
data work.TO_current_2;
set work.TO_current;
%Do curr_day= &Today. %TO curr_day = 1 %BY -1;
%let eval_day = %eval(&curr_day +(&last_day_prev));
rename Total_out_bal_odd_&curr_day. = total_out_bal_odd_&eval_day.;
rename Balance_&curr_day. = Balance_&eval_day.;
rename Team_&curr_day. = team_&eval_day.;
rename Bucket_odd_&curr_day. = Bucket_odd_&eval_day.;
rename Bucket_assig_odd_&curr_day. = Bucket_assig_odd_&eval_day.;
rename DPD_NDD_&curr_day. = DPD_NDD_&eval_day.;
%END;
run;
%MEND;
%rename;
```

the loop does not stop (as I would expect) at 1, but goes beyond until 0.

The work.TO_current table does indeed contain variables indexed to _0, but the whole purpose of this code should be to prevent them from being renamed.
I know this question is probably silly for more experienced SAS users, but I can't wrap my head around it... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to specifiy an integer (or a macro expression that generates an integer) to use as the final macro-variable iteration value for the [`%TO`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_036/mcrolref/p0ri72c3ud2fdtn1qzs2q9vvdiwk.htm) argument.

Change your statement from

```
%DO curr_day=&today. %TO curr_day = 1 %BY -1;
```

to

```
%DO curr_day=&today. %TO 1 %BY -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

Since the digit `1` does not equal the string `curr_day` you told the %DO loop that the target value was 0.  If you want the target value to be 1 just say that directly.

```
%DO curr_day=&today. %TO 1 %BY -1;
```